# How to add traces in data array from JSON data for Plotlyjs programmaticaly?

Tags: javascript, angular, plotly.js

I want to get JSON data from an API call and from that I wanna plot one scatter graph by using Plotly js library.

What I tried so far is to take the unique label from the the array which will be consider as different  trace points in the graph so the same label should comes under one traces. Here is the part where I stuck - I am not able to create traces from the label valued and pass it in data array.

this is the data I want to plot

```
  let data2=[    
  {Dim_1: 343.1929931641, Dim_2: -551.9379272461, label: 253},
  {Dim_1: -40.2070579529, Dim_2: 86.8081054688, label: 161},
  {Dim_1: -423.3389282227, Dim_2: -199.669052124, label: 22},
  {Dim_1: 316.681060791, Dim_2: 400.6117858887, label: 372},
  {Dim_1: 311.0101623535, Dim_2: -74.6273803711, label: 14},
  {Dim_1: 694.282043457, Dim_2: 212.6262359619, label: 253},
  {Dim_1: -71.8872528076, Dim_2: 564.7513427734, label: 138},
  {Dim_1: 704.6930541992, Dim_2: -254.9784088135, label: 22},
  {Dim_1: -433.4716186523, Dim_2: 268.049407959, label: 129},
  {Dim_1: -46.0619773865, Dim_2: -388.825378418, label: 28},
  .........
 ]
  for (var item in data2) {
  x_axis.push(data2[item].Dim_1);
  y_axis.push(data2[item].Dim_2);
  labels.push(data2[item].label);
 }

 let trace;
 const uniqueLabels = [...new Set(labels)].sort();
 for (let label of uniqueLabels) {
  data.push(
    (trace = {
      x: x_axis,
      y: y_axis,
      mode: "markers",
      type: "scatter",
      name: "trace-" + label
     })
   );
  }
  Plotly.newPlot("myDiv", data);
  }
```

SO actual result would be same label name and corresponding values should consider under a single trace and so on
 {Dim_1: 694.282043457, Dim_2: 212.6262359619, label: 253},
 {Dim_1: 343.1929931641, Dim_2: -551.9379272461, label: 253} this two will come under same trace because label value is same.

Comment: do you have a working demo?

Comment: @joyBlanks sorry mate- I don't have a working demo now. However you can tell me if any other details you need. I am simply want to plot scatter graph from JSON data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to group trace data by "label".
This will work with custom filter function (reference : [Custom filter for object](https://blog.naver.com/zoonykh/221505489698))

```
function _filter(list, predi) {
    let newList = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (predi(list[i])) newList.push(list[i]);
    }
    return newList;
}
```

After create unique name array(uniqueLabels), use custom filter function as below.

```
for (let label of uniqueLabels) {

    let xValueList = [];
    let yValueList = [];
    let textList = [];

    /* Here is what you need.
    Create filtered array from data2 with custom filter function.    
    */
    let filteredList= _filter(data2, (traceData) => traceData.label == label);

    for(let item of filteredList){      
       xValueList.push(item.Dim_1);
       yValueList.push(item.Dim_2);
       textList.push(item.label);
    }


    trace.push({
      x: xValueList,
      y: yValueList,
      mode: "markers",
      type: "scatter",
      text: textList,
      showlegend: true,
      name: "trace-" + label
     });

  }

Plotly.newPlot("myDiv", data);
```

PS : This would be helpful how to make demo for question.
https://codepen.io/jornathan/pen/jOOrqyQ

Comment: - This is something I am looking for and it works fine. Thanks for the solution.